# Prevent page breaks in puppeteer pdf

Tags: html, css, node.js, puppeteer, page-break-inside

I have html like

```
<table>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

This template is getting converting to PDF with puppeteer where my tabular data is splitting across two pages however i dont want tabular data to split across the pages

I have tried all the solutions of SO for this issue https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6366
but still I am not able to find the solution
I have tried page-break-inside :avoid in tbody/tr its not working
I know this css works on block level element  so I have tried with wrapping the table in div and applied that css on div still table is breaking in pages
Please help if you have any solution

Comment: I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557421/removing-page-breaks-from-puppeteer-pdf but that's also not working

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to generate your pdf for `print`. To do it, use this method :

```
await page.emulateMediaType('print');
```

This will allow you to control the presentation of content for print with css like `break-before`, see more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media

#### Answer

You have multiple solutions so :

- If your table is small enough, you can put it on one page, with a css rule like `style="page-break-before: always"`, to ensure that it start on a new page.
- If your table is too long (most of the case for dynamics table), generate your pdf for print will repeat the table header on each page, so the pdf will still be readable. If you need to ensure that some elements groups will stay together, you can apply css rules like we saw above.

It could be an hard work to obtain precise render with puppeteer, but puppeteer is probably the best to do it for now. Be brave.

Comment: I have tried with await page.emulateMediaType('print');    along with the media print {tbody  {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
} but still its not working , page is still breaking in between the content of table @Flament Mickaël

Comment: Also, If I am doing `tbody{display: block ; page-break-inside : avoid } ` then it works but the table layout gets affected after that - due to which I cant use this css @Flament Mickaël

Comment: I had a slightly different question; my pdf generation breaked pages within table rows. This comment helped me, as `tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }` solved my problem. Thanks!